# shell script error -'expecting do' error

Tags: shell

[image: Screenshot of the workspace]
I used shell script for downloading multiple PDB files from PDB server, directly. I am getting this error when I tried running the script. 
In the terminal, I typed the following.

> sh a.sh

a.sh: 2: a.sh: Syntax error: word unexpected (expecting "do")

**a.sh**

```
for i in 'cat list'
do
wget http://www.rcsb.org/pdb/files/$i.pdb.gz
done
```

**list**
1HLG
5EW4

Comment: What's a.sh? Where does it come from?

Comment: a.sh is the name of the script

Comment: Did you, at any time, edit this file using a Windows editor?

Comment: No, I did not. Only LINUX

Comment: The code that you show will not produce the error that you show: Something is missing from the description.

Comment: Oh sorry, I thought I missed something. 'cat list' is probably something you'll need to check, but that's just a guess.

Comment: `'cat list'` is a fixed string.  It won't produce a _syntax error_.  Syntax errors occur _before_ the code runs.    (By the way, if you were expecting the program to read from the file `list`, then the code needs to change, preferably to something like `while IFS= read -r line; do ...; done <list`.)

Answer (score 0):

This doesn't do what one might expect:

```
for i in 'cat list'
```

In the above, `'cat list'` is a fixed string.  The loop over `i` will be run once and only once with the value `i='cat list'`.

If you want to loop over the contents of the file list, some people would run:

```
for i in `cat list`
```

Or:

```
for i in $(cat list)
```

The above, however, subjects the contents of `list` to *word splitting* and *pathname expansion* and this is likely not what you want.  To avoid that, run:

```
while IFS= read -r i
do
   wget "http://www.rcsb.org/pdb/files/$i.pdb.gz"
done <list
```

The above runs `wget` once for each line of `list` and the lines are of `list` are used unchanged.  (If the lines of `list` have leading or trailing whitespace that you want to ignore, then remove `IFS=` from the code.)

Note that, in the above code, the shell variable `$i` is used inside double-quotes.  This prevents *word splitting* and *pathname expansion* from being performed on the URL.

Comment: Again it returns the same error.    >a.sh: 4: a.sh: Syntax error: "done" unexpected (expecting "do")

Comment: Can you run `od -c a.sh` and report the output?

Comment: 0000000   w   h   i   l   e       I   F   S   =       r   e   a   d                                 0000020   -   r       i  \r  \n   d   o  \r  \n               w   g   e                               0000040   t       "   h   t   t   p   :   /   /   w   w   w   .   r   c                               0000060   s   b   .   o   r   g   /   p   d   b   /   f   i   l   e   s                         0000100   /   $   i   .   p   d   b   .   g   z   "  \r  \n   d   o   n                       0000120   e       <   l   i   s   t  \r  \n                                                        0000131

Comment: @ShilpaJanarthanan Thank you.  _That clears it up._  The sequence of `\r \n` characters, which is repeated several times, shows that this file has DOS/Windows line endings.   One solution is to run this file through a utility like `dos2unix`.  Alternatively, create the file from scratch in a unix-friendly editor.